# Cómo llenar listview desde JSON?

Tags: android, json, listview

Buenas a todos. La duda que tengo es cómo llenar un listview desde una url que me devuelve JSON. Aparentemente las lee, pero no las mete en la lista y no sé por qué puede ser.

Uno de los error que tira es este:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Names must be strings, but 8 is of type java.lang.Integer at character 19 of  { 'clinicas': [{ 8: 'Centro EQ' },{ 6: 'Pinmd' }]}
```

Creo que el error está en mi clase DataParser.java que es la siguiente:

```
public class DataParser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer> {
Context c;
String jsonData;
ListView lv;
ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<String> clinicas = new ArrayList<>();


public DataParser(Context c, String jsonData, ListView lv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.jsonData = jsonData;
    this.lv = lv;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Parse");
    pd.setMessage("Pasring..Please wait");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.parseData();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
    super.onPostExecute(integer);
    pd.dismiss();
    if(integer == 1) {
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(c, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clinicas);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(c, clinicas.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

private int parseData()
{
    try
    {
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo = null;

        clinicas.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

            String idclin = jo.getString("idclin");
            String nameclin = jo.getString("clinicas");

            clinicas.add(idclin);
            clinicas.add(nameclin);
        }
        return 1;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El JSON que recibo es el siguiente:

```
{ 'clinicas': [{ 8: 'Centro EQ' },{ 6: 'Pinmd' }]}
```

Comment: pides el valor `idclin` pero no veo nada de eso en el JSON que recibes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas tratando un JSONObject como si fuera un JSONArray  :

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonData);
```

Cuando deberia de ser:

```
 JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
 JSONArray arr = jobject.getJSONArray("clinicas");
```

Tambien las llaves `idclin` y `clinicas` no existen en el json que nos muestras.

Tendras que buscar todas las propiedades del json y por cada key, buscar el valor y asi podras obtener las clinicas:

```
JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONArray arr = jobject.getJSONArray("clinicas");
JSONObject jo;
clinicas.clear();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    jo = arr.getJSONObject(i);

    Iterator<String> keys = jo.keys();

    while(keys.hasNext())
    {
        String keyName = keys.next();
        System.out.println(keyName);
        clinicas.add(jo.getString(keyName));
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, ya voy entendiendo qué estaba mal.
Aunque en el while en clinicas.add(jo.get(keyName));
me da el siguiente error:
add
(java.lang.String)
in ArrayList cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.Object)

Tiene que ver por la forma en que declaré el ArrayList en la clase? ArrayList<String> clinicas = new ArrayList<>();

Gracias por responder

Comment: Reemplaza `jo.get()` por `jo.getString()`. Mira mi respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Ya lo reemplacé, pero sigo teniendo el mismo error que está en el post.

Comment: Verifica que nos estas mostrando el json completo.

Comment: Sí, es así de corto, sólo esas 2 clínicas.